# Correcting Trajectory Tracks in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-basemap

I'm running into a problem where some plotted points are connecting back to the first plot point after being plotted. I need to find a way to close or clear track points after they're plotted in matplotlib and also how to make each line it's own color.

[image]

**Sample data from text file:**

```
CMCI,36,16.9,-68.1
AVNI,0,15.7,-60.1
AVNI,12,16.1,-62.8
AVNI,24,16.5,-65.5
AVNI,36,17,-68.5
AVNI,48,17.6,-71.5
BAMD,12,16.3,-62.1
BAMM,168,23.1,-87.9
BAMS,84,20.3,-79.5
BAMS,96,20.6,-81.6
BAMS,108,21.1,-83.9
BAMS,120,21.5,-85.9
BAMS,132,22,-87.9
CLIP,12,16,-61.6
CLIP,24,16.4,-63.4
CLIP,36,17.1,-65.1
CLIP,48,18,-66.9
CLIP,72,20.2,-70
```

The final two columns in the text file are lat/lon.

**Code:**

```
data = np.genfromtxt("/home/.../.../.../all", delimiter=',', skip_header=True)

model = data[:,0]
fhr = data[:,1]
lats = data[:,2]
lons = data[:,3]

x,y = m(lons,lats)

plt.plot(x,y,'ro-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: are all the tracks in one file? If so, what tells you which coord should be in which line?

Comment: Yes, all the tracks are in the same text file in the same format. And I'm guessing plt.plot performs that task? Still a beginner with Python...

Comment: Well, that's why they are all the same colour and are joining up. You need to find some way to split them up into separate tracks, then you will have different colours and no connecting lines from the end of one track to the start of the next. Are they all a standard length? or will the `model` or `fhr` columns help you to split them up?

Comment: The `model` column will help to split them up for sure. I'm thinking that I need to use an if statement in here somewhere to achieve that.

Comment: ok, so all coords with `model = ANVI` are one track, and `model = CLIP` are another, etc?

Comment: Exactly! I need to separate each of the models to their own track and then make sure that each model has it's own color.

Comment: ok, see my answer, coming up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot each track separately, using your `model` column to index `x` and `y`. You'll need to expand the `models` list to include all the possible models in your data file.

```
data = np.genfromtxt("/home/.../.../.../all", delimiter=',', skip_header=True)

model = data[:,0]
fhr = data[:,1]
lats = data[:,2]
lons = data[:,3]

models = ['ANVI', 'BAMS', 'CLIP']
cols = ['r','g','b']

for i in range(len(models)):
    plt.plot(x[model==models[i]],y[model==models[i]],
             marker='o',linestyle='-',color=cols[i])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the code! Unfortunately, only the first point of one of the models is plotting... Image: http://i.imgur.com/bza7wd3.png. There are no plotted individual lines...